# Eclipse error when trying to configure for using Groovy in a Gradle project

Tags: linux, eclipse, gradle, groovy

On a Windows machine I've been using Groovy in Gradle projects in Eclipse for some time now.  Now I'm trying to configure for a Linux machine. (Linux Mint MATE). `uname -a` gives this:

> Linux mike-Latitude-E6410 4.4.0-53-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2
>   15:58:04 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Eclipse Oxygen.  Installed Groovy (2.4.15) using this link: http://dist.springsource.org/snapshot/GRECLIPSE/e4.7/

Installed Gradle (4.7) using Buildship Gradle Integration 2.0.

Then I put this line in build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.15'
```

I make a new "source directory" under the project: src/test/groovy.

I make a new file under that: "Test.groovy".

I put one line in that: `println "hello world"`.

Without changing the "source sets" in build.gradle yet I now see one of those dreaded "red exclamation marks" next to the one line of the file.  The message is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type groovy.lang.GroovyObject cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - The type groovy.lang.MetaClass cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
    - implements groovy.lang.Script.run
```

There are surprisingly few reports (particularly recent ones) of this problem in SO or more generally when I search.

One suggests adding the Groovy Runtime Libraries to the build path configuration ... did that: not solved.

NB I have also tried repeatedly 1) rebuilding the project 2) refreshing Gradle 3) running the "build" task 4) closing Eclipse and starting up again.

NB2 I have not yet installed Groovy or Gradle in the general system: only for Eclipse. Could this be anything to do with it? Seems unlikely.

Comment: Could you post your whole `build.gradle` file? Do you encounter these errors only in Eclipse or also if you build and run the code with Gradle?

Comment: Thanks... it was a silly mistake by me: see my answer.  Apologies for wasting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this was a "schoolboy error".

I just had to include this line in build.gradle (I haven't currently got access to my other machine so wasn't able to make the comparison).

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
```

Will leave the question, unless there is massive objection, because it might help others who get puzzled...

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was: I had put my `XXXSpec.groovy` file under `src/test/java` instead of `src/test/groovy`